# Passing URL argument to a link (<a href...)

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I am working on a Sencha/Cordova application. I need to pass a URL as argument to a method in `href` method. I am using the following code to do this:

```
<a href = '#Controller/method'>
```

I need to pass an argument to this `method` and the argument is an URL. Inside the controller the method is defined like:

```
method:function(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use escape character (`\"`) to insert the result of the method in your link.

If your method returns a link like this:

```
method: function(){
    ...
    return aLink;
}
```

Do something like this:

```
var link = '<a href=\"' + method() + '\"'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new route to your controller and pass the url to that. I.e.

```
Ext.define('Yourapp.controller.Action', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
        'Ext.app.Route'
    ],
    config: {
        routes: {
            'method/:url': function(url) {
                console.log(url);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can pass your URL to this by using

```
<a href = '#Controller/method/your_URL_encoded_url'>
```

I hope this is working for you. However I'm not sure it is a good practice to pass in URLs on this way. Knowing to the reason why you need this might result better solutions.